# Error: File ended while scanning definition of \pgfplots@legend@to@name@grouplegend

Tags: pgfplots, errors, compiling

I am working a project while all of a sudden the above error appeared and the Latex wouldn't compile anymore. The strange thing is, when I go back to versions of half an hour ago, when it still did compile, it doesn't work anymore either. I have desperately been looking for the error for an hour now.

It is quite hard to make a working example for this, so I included a picture of the error. Can somebody give me directions on where to look?
[image]

UPDATE: Somehow making a copy of the project and opening the copy fixes the error. The old file still doesn't compile.

Comment: It seems like you're using OverLeaf. You should delete the `.aux` file, which may have been corrupted during a previous compilation (click on Logs and output files, then on Clear cached files). That explains why a new project would fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the problem! Always good to know where the error came from.
And yes, I am using OverLeaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.aux` files are caches to improve compilation, but could become corrupt. You should delete the `.aux` file, which may have been corrupted during a previous compilation (click on Logs and output files, then on Clear cached files). This also explains why a new project would fix the problem since it doesn't have any auxiliary files to begin with.